# keep a rule and be able to update it for a given start date in the database

Tags: sql, rules

I am looking to update a rule in a database for a given date. The current rule should not be modified because it is used by the system. However, I must be able to update it for a given date.

The idea would be to add a new record to the database with a start date. From this date the previous rule should no longer be used.

I don't know how to diagram this. You may also have another point of view on this subject.

Comment: We need more context. There's not enough information here about exactly what you mean to answer this. We don't even know what kind of database you have.

Comment: I will try to provide more precision.

I need to be able to create a calculation rule, which can be updated from a given date.

Rule 1 is created and applies from 01/10/2023. Rule 1 is updated with an application date of 01/11/2023, which involves the creation of a new rule (Rule 2) with a start date of 01/11/2023.

Between 01/10/2023 and before 01/11/2023 rule 1 is applied.

From 01/11/2023 rule 2 is applied.

Comment: Take [tour], read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: What kind of rule? How and where are they defined?

Comment: this is a rule of loyalty

Comment: You need to be more specific: how is the rule you mentioned enforced by your database (which rdbms do you use: tag it); is it in a stored procedure? is it on a table trigger? is it a column and/or table constraint, or is it a `RULE` in SQLServer  (created with CREATE RULE)?

Comment: Rules can be seen as campaigns stored in a table. They allow you to determine the number of points to be awarded when making a purchase from a date or between 2 dates.